# 400 error when accessing S3 bucket in ap-south-1 region using boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have been trying to access S3 bucket from a python program running on EC2 instance. The code and error is attached:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection         
import boto           

conn=S3Connection()            
bucket=conn.get_bucket('nplr1')
```

**Error:**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 140, in <module>
    main()
  File "Main.py", line 33, in main
    conn.get_all_buckets()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 444, in get_all_buckets
    response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code><Message>The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.</Message>
```

**This is my /etc/boto.cfg file**

```
[Credentials]              
aws_access_key_id = 'id'            
aws_secret_access_key = 'key'

[s3]       
region='ap-south-1'           
aws_access_key_id ='id'             
aws_secret_access_key = 'key'
```

What is the issue with this? Why am I not able to access the bucket?

Comment: I believe 'host' should be 'region'.

Comment: Hey @zatta , I tried replacing host with region and I got this error:boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden

Comment: Is the bucketname correct? If yes, does the keys provided have access to it?

Comment: Hi @franklinsijo , I edited my question. I am getting the error >The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. Do i have to change anything with AWS config file?

Comment: Are your keys correct? and why do you have two sets of keys?

Comment: Both the sets are actually same. With all those errors, I have been trying few things and this is one of those.

Comment: Check whether the keys are correct and still valid. And you do not have credentials defined in any other file right? can you do `aws configure list` and see this is the only file with keys!

Comment: Yup, that is the only file containing keys

Comment: Check the region if it's correct. There is no ap-south-1 region. I see that there are                                                                                             Asia Pacific (Singapore) ap-southeast-1 apigateway.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com HTTPS
Asia Pacific (Sydney) ap-southeast-2 apigateway.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com HTTPS

Comment: Both my EC2 and S3 are located in ap-south-1 region. When I tried `aws s3 ls` I got my bucket name as output, In my program too, I am able to list my bucket using get_all_buckets() function but  Ikeep getting ResponseError 400: Bad Request when I use get_bucket() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to the fact that `ap-south-1` uses Signature v4 for signing requests, and `boto` doesn't recognise to this. Neither does `boto3`.

However, you can override the signature configuration. Here's some working code in `boto3`:

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

s3 = boto3.resource('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
bucket=s3.get_bucket('nplr1')
```

For `boto`, I managed to get it working by explicitly stating the host for `ap-south-1`:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection         
import boto           

conn=S3Connection(host='s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com')            
bucket=conn.get_bucket('nplr1')
```

Useful information was gained from:

- [Using boto for AWS S3 Buckets for Signature V4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400105/using-boto-for-aws-s3-buckets-for-signature-v4)
- [S3 using boto and SigV4 - missing host parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26744712/174777)
- [How to configure authorization mechanism inline with boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33577503/174777)
- [Need way to override client config when creating resource (for s3v4 sigs)](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/168)
- [AWS Regions and Endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not accessing the `[s3]` profile within your credentials file. Profiles need to be explicitly requested when creating the client connection. Therefore, the region probably isn't being picked-up.

I recommend you test your credentials via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). For example, running `aws s3 ls` will test whether you have permission to list your Amazon S3 buckets. If that works, then you can do further commands to test your permissions (eg `aws s3 ls s3://nplr1`).

Comment: Hey @John , I tried running the command but I got the same error. I tried the command `aws configure` and added the credentials. Then I tried `aws s3 ls` and found my bucket successfully. But when I run the program I get error 400: Bad Request

Comment: @John There is `ap-south-1` region. It was recently added.

Comment: Ah! I managed to reproduce your `400: Bad Request` error. See my other answer.